# Remove part of $(hostname)') in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am running a script to automatically update a field inside a database with the servers hostname

```
updatevar="UPDATE email_lists SET owneremail = REPLACE(owneremail, 'replacethis321', '$(hostname)');"
```

However, the hostname is "`xyz.com`"; how would I make it only be "`xyz`"? The script needs to remove the "`.com`" part. This is used on multiple servers so I can't just set it to `xyz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `$(hostname)` directly, assign it to a shell variable so you can [use PE expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) at expansion time:

```
hostname=$(hostname)
updatevar="... ${hostname%%.*} ..."
```

The use of `%%.*` trims everything after the first dot. You could instead use `${hostname%.com}` if you only wanted to remove the suffix `.com` (but leave `.org`, `.net`, etc alone).

Alternately, instead of `$(hostname)`, use `$(hostname -s)` if your operating system supports it; this is the "short" form, truncated at the first dot.

---

That said -- using string substitutions to form SQL expressions is bad form (and since bash doesn't typically give you a way to use bind variables in running SQL, it's usually necessary/appropriate to use a different language if you genuinely want to do the job right). Even the Wooledge bash guide [explicitly calls out database interaction as a limitation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can pipe to `awk` instead of getting the `hostname` in a separate variable.

```
$(hostname | awk -F "." '{print $1}')
```